# JPA cascade - deletion is not working when id is different in join table

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

[image]

I am using spring JPA to insert and delete the records in these tables. I can able to insert the record, but deletion is not happening due to different id's in emp_workstation table. If both employee_id and workstation_id were same then delete is working fine, but if both the id's were not same then delete not happening in employee table and emp_workstation table (cascade has set to 'ALL'). Does anybody face this problem before or know how to solve this issue?

### Employee.java

```
 @Setter
    @Getter
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
    @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "employee")
    public class Employee {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sq_employee_id")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "sq_employee_id", sequenceName = "sq_employee_id", allocationSize = 1)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "employee_name", length = 50)
        private String name;

          @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "emp_workstation", joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "workstation_id") })
        private Workstation workstation;
    }
```

### Workstation.java

```
  @Setter
    @Getter
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
    @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "workstation")
    public class Workstation {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sq_workstation_id")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "sq_workstation_id", sequenceName = "sq_workstation_id", allocationSize = 1)
        private Long id;

         @Column(name = "workstation_name", nullable = false, length = 100)
        private String name;

         @Column(name = "workstation_area", nullable = false, length = 100)
        private String name;

         @OneToOne(mappedBy = "workStation")
        private Employee employee;
        }
```

Example: In EMP_WORKSTATION table, if EMPLOYEE_ID and WORKSTATION_ID were same then deletion is working fine. but if both id were different then deletion is not working.

Thanks

Comment: Enable SQL logging and post the generated queries.

Comment: The problem already mentioned in the question itself. In EMP_WORKSTATION table both employee_id and workstation_id is not match. Due to that cascade is not working.

Comment: Yes, I have read your question. `OneToOne` with shared PK and with independent PKs are both valid approaches which is why I thought the generated  SQL might be useful as the mappings look fine. How are you firing this delete operation?

Comment: What is your code calling the delete on? The Employee or the Workstation?

Comment: Through postman sending request. I am sending employeeId and my JPA repositary configure as Employee which contains all the table details.                       @Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}

Comment: You should all relevant code not just what you think is relevant. What repo method are you calling `deleteById(id)`?

Comment: yes deleteById(employeeId)